# MATLAB: Solving series of equations to systematically adjust probability estimates

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write MATLAB code that takes in estimated probabilities `x` and `y` and maps them on to an adjusted set of probabilities `p` and `q`.

Usually the input probabilities `x` and `y` won't add up to 1, and so the point of the code is to adjust the probabilities so that they do add up to 1.

Here's an example where  `x + y = 1.03`

```
syms n p q x y
eqn1 = x == 0.7813;
eqn2 = y == 0.2487;
eqn3 = p^n == x;
eqn4 = q^n == y;
eqn5 = log(x)./log(p) == log(y)./log(q);
eqn6 = x^(1/n) == p;
eqn7 = y^(1/n) == q;
eqn8 = p + q == 1;

sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, eqn6, eqn7, eqn8], [n p q x y])
```

The value `n` is applied to both x and y, and it deliberately has the effect of 'pushing down' low probability estimates more so than high probability ones.

I know that in the example above the answer should be `n≈0.946139, p≈0.7704, q≈0.2297` but haven't been able to write any code that produces such an output.

The code above produces an empty struct. I have also tried `vpasolve` which also did not work. I am unsure if my solutions are failing because I've misspecified the problem or because I'm using the wrong function type in MATLAB.

Comment: When solve return an empty struct without warning means that there is no solution, if there is a warning the solver didn’t find the solution but a solution exist. Do you get a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of redundancy in the equations here.

`eqn6` and `eqn7` imply `eqn3` and `eqn4` respectively. Furthermore, `eqn3` and `eqn4` imply `eqn5`. We also don't need `eqn1` and `eqn2` which define `x` and `y` as constants since these are more effectively handled using direct substitution. I would guess that these redundancies are the reasons MATLAB is getting confused but I'm not exactly sure.

Also, it's probably a bit of overkill to use the symbolic toolbox for this since there's probably no closed form solution, but if you must then here's a solution.

```
x = 0.7813;
y = 0.2487;
syms n p q
eqn6 = x^(1/n) == p;
eqn7 = y^(1/n) == q;
eqn8 = p + q == 1;
sol = solve([eqn6, eqn7, eqn8], [p q n]);

p = sol.p
q = sol.q
n = sol.n
```

**Results**:

```
Warning: Cannot solve symbolically. Returning a numeric approximation instead. 
> In solve (line 304)
  In q51941792_2 (line 7) 
p = 0.77034051295869623476715256144042
q = 0.22965948704130376523284743855958     
n = 0.94585921162748018347665683036153
```

Notice that the solver can't find a closed form solution so it defaults to a numerical optimization approach.

---

If you have the Optimization Toolbox then you could use [`fsolve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) instead which is more appropriate (and much faster). To use `fsolve` you need to define a function which takes one input vector and returns one output vector. The objective of `fsolve` is the find the input vector which results in all zero outputs. We rearrange `eqn6`, `eqn7`, and `eqn8` to form this function. You can read the documentation for more information.

```
x = 0.7813;
y = 0.2487;

% define optimization function assumes ary = [p, q, n]
f = @(ary) [x^(1/ary(3)) - ary(1); ...   % eqn6
            y^(1/ary(3)) - ary(2); ...   % eqn7
            ary(1) + ary(2) - 1];        % eqn8

% initial estimate
p0 = x;
q0 = y;
n0 = 1;

% solve
fsolve_opts = optimoptions('fsolve', 'OptimalityTolerance', 0, 'FunctionTolerance', 1e-12);
sol = fsolve(f, [p0; q0; n0], fsolve_opts);

p = sol(1)
q = sol(2)
n = sol(3)
```

**Result**:

```
p = 0.770340512958696
q = 0.229659487041304
n = 0.945859211627480
```

---

*Existence of a solution*

There are situations where no solutions exist. For example if `x > 1` and `y > 0 & y < 1` then both `p` and `q` are positive but one of them is greater than 1 (depending on the value of `n`) but this contradicts `eqn8` so no solution exists. If you want to use this approach you'll need to have guarantees that a solution exists. I believe that a sufficient condition is that `x` and `y` are both between 0 and 1 although I haven't proven it.